# pycurl 302 response get location value

Tags: python, protocols, response, pycurl

I am trying to get, some values from pycurl response because some different protocols produce some errors like

```
pycurl Error: [1] Protocol tel not supported or disabled in libcurl
```

I have to use `followlocation 1` and, has different protocol like `tel:` i have to get just location of value, not to follow that link, is this possible?

I tried to get this value with,

```
def header(self,buf):
    self.HEADER_BUFFER = buf

c.setopt(pycurl.HEADERFUNCTION, self.header)
```

But couldn't get any data with this method.

Answer (score 1):

Use this two pycurl options:

```
c.setopt(pycurl.CURLOPT_HEADER, 1) ## return Response header
c.setopt(pycurl.FOLLOWLOCATION, 0) ## no redirect handling
```

Now at the response result on your pycurl, you find a Response header `Location: ...`. From there parse your link that you wanted.